# Google Sheets- How to concat each item in column 1 with each and every item in column 2

Tags: google-sheets

In a google spreadsheet, I have 2 columns of data. I'd like to create a third column that concatenates each item in column A with every and each item in column B, and add a space between the two values.

Result I'm trying to get:

**Column A**
Red
Blue

**Column B**
Square
Circle
Rectangle

**Column C**      Required Result
Red Square
Red Circle
Red Rectangle
Blue Square
Blue Circle
Blue Rectangle

I've been trying various concatenations within ArrayFormula but can't get a formula that works as required. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=transpose(split(textjoin("|",1,array_constrain(ArrayFormula(A2:A4&" "&transpose(B2:B4)),2,3)),"|"))
```

Comment: A small caveat - this type of solution has a built-in size limit, when the concatenated text of all possible combinations exceeds 50,000 characters. If there is a danger of that happening, you may have to look for a JavaScript solution.